# Add incremental index in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT WORKORDERID AS WOID FROM WORKORDER WO
```

This will return a list of workorder IDs in my WO table.

```
   WOID
  |AAB1|
  |AAB2|
  |AAB3|
```

But I would like to add index numbers for each of the work order IDs like this:

```
SELECT WORKORDERID ||'-'||[index] AS WOID FROM WORKORDER WO
```

My desired result is:

```
       WOID
      |AAB1-1|
      |AAB1-2|
      |AAB1-3|
      |AAB1-4|
      |AAB2-1|
      |AAB2-2|
      |AAB2-3|
      |AAB2-4|
      |AAB3-1|
      |AAB3-2|
      |AAB3-3|
      |AAB3-4|
```

The only way I can think of is create another table with index 1-4 and then join these two tables. My question is is it possible to achieve this result within just one SELECT statement without having to create another table?

Comment: You can create an "inline table" using a CTE. No need for this table to be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SQL> with test (workorderid) as
  2    (select 'AAB1' from dual union all
  3     select 'AAB2' from dual union all
  4     select 'AAB3' from dual
  5    )
  6  select workorderid ||'-'|| column_value result
  7  from test,
  8       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                           connect by level <= 4
 10                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by 1;

RESULT
-------------------------
AAB1-1
AAB1-2
AAB1-3
AAB1-4
AAB2-1
AAB2-2
AAB2-3
AAB2-4
AAB3-1
AAB3-2
AAB3-3
AAB3-4

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select wo.woid || '-' || n.n as new_woid
from WORKORDER wo cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all
      select 2 as n from dual union all
      select 3 as n from dual union all
      select 4 as n from dual
     ) n
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
with idx (n) as (
  select 1 from dual union all
  select 2 from dual union all
  select 3 from dual union all
  select 4 from dual
)
select
    wo.workorderid || '-' || idx.n
  from workorder wo, idx
```